# MYSQL ORDER BY FIELD from a list from and other table

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm scraching my head on this one for a long time and I don't know how to solve this.

I have 2 mysql tables

Table1

```
+----+----------------------+
| id | name    | order_list |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | Bob     |    3       |
|  2 | Marc    |    2       |
|  3 | Edith   |    1       |
|  4 | John    |    4       |
+----+----------------------+
```

Table2

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | user_id |  sale   |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 |   3     |   30    |
|  2 |   2     |   40    |
|  3 |   1     |   100   |
|  4 |   3     |   75    |
|  5 |   2     |   40    |
|  6 |   1     |   100   |
|  7 |   4     |   75    |
+----+-------------------+
```

I need to have all purchase from table2 ORDER BY the order_list from table 1 of the user_id from table 2.

Right now I'm doing this in PHP like this.
1 query to get the id from employee from table 1 order by order_list.
A loop 
Inside 1 query for each employee to get the sale

I need every sale independent, not sum or group by.

```
query to get the id from table 1 order by order_list
loop
    query the table2 for the sale of the looped employee
end loop
```

I know that this can be done with something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM table2 ORDER BY FIELD (id,order from table 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic `join` should suffice:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.user_id = t1.id
order by t1.order_list;
```

Or, if you prefer, put a subquery in the `order by`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
order by (select t1.order_list from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.user_id);
```

Comment: I have a very large quantity of data in the DB. When I try the JOIN my server work for many second before giving me the result. But with the subquery also instant. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* FROM table2 a
LEFT JOIN table1 b on a.user_id = b.id 
ORDER BY b.order_list
```

Just join them so you can access columns from the 2 tables.